# 1D Random Walk variant

Tags: programming, random

I am making a notebook that is a variation to the traditional 1d random walk problem. 
The normal 1D random walk can be simulated easily by

```
Map[Accumulate, {RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {100}]}] // Flatten
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9,
>   8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6,
>   7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0,
>   -1, -2, -1, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1,
>   -2, -1, -2, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2}

As shown, this returns a list of positions along the x-axis for each of the 100 steps.

However, instead of choosing a set number of steps, I would like to discontinue the walk when a certain points is reached. This, of course, would make the length of the list of locations vary between each run as it will take a different number of steps to reach x = 10, for instance. How can I do this (without a For loop)?

Comment: [This is worth a thorough read](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhileList.html)

Comment: closely related: [sample times at which the random walk crosses the boundary](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44574/5478)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [ssch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1517/ssch) alluded to in a comment this can be easily done with `NestWhileList`:

```
NestWhileList[# + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] &, 0, # < 10 &]
```

This is hardly the only way to proceed however.  You could for example `Sow` and `Reap` values from within a recursion:

```
f[x_] /; x < 10 := f @ Sow[x + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]];

Reap[f[0]][[2, 1]]
```

This actually converts to iteration, and is therefore limited by `$IterationLimit` rather than `$RecursionLimit`.  You can raise `$IterationLimit` to increase the maximum number of steps.

You could use replacement rules and `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
{0} //. {h___, x_} /; x < 10 :> {h, x, x + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]}
```

---

Rojo posted an answer that uses a couple of advanced techniques to cleverly optimize this problem.  One would do well to take a close look at it; one of the techniques is very nice and new to me and I'm not new at this game.

Nevertheless, reasonably fast performance can be had with a significantly simpler block-based method.  This is about a third slower than his method in my tests but the code is probably easier to understand and quite a bit shorter.  The block size (here `1*^4`) can be adjusted according to your average run length.

```
f[target_Integer] :=
  Block[{new, pos, $RecursionLimit = 1*^9},
    new = # + Accumulate @ RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 1*^4];
    pos = Position[new, target, 1, 1];
    If[pos === {},
      Sow @ new; #0 @ Last @ new,
      Sow @ Take[new, pos[[1, 1]] ]
    ]
  ] &

SeedRandom[7]
Join @@ Reap[ f[500][0] ][[2, 1]] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.233, 19262470}
> ```

By comparison:

```
SeedRandom[7]
walker[500] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.921, 19257825}
> ```

(The length is slightly different as not every number from the PRNG is used.)

---

Update: Rojo improved his answer and now:

```
SeedRandom[7]

walker[502] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.281, 19446001}
> ```

I had to use `502` to get a similar length because the PRNG was again used a little differently.

Comment: Also, watchout, the OP doesn't seem to want a 0 step as an option

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, do you know why `Join @@ Reap[f[500][0]][[2, 1]] // Length` would work fine but `x = Join @@ Reap[f[500][0]][[2, 1]];` causes my kernel to crash (v9) with no message? (Using `SeedRandom[7]`.) If I change `$RecursionLimit=Infinity` then my `x=` line works fine. I'm just trying to understand why it does not work with the first `$RecursionLimit` if `Length` does.

Comment: @mfvonh That sounds very strange.  The identical code *doesn't* crash when you add `Length`?  I cannot see how that is anything but a bug.  Does `Length[ x = Join @@ Reap[f[500][0]][[2, 1]] ];` crash?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A little embarrassing--I didn't reset my random seed. It looks like the next walk on seed 7 (after running the first) does not reach the target within a manageable number of steps, at least on my machine, and the kernel just quits.

Comment: @mfvonh Yes, that can/will happen when the maximum stack depth is exceeded. (We *all* make mistakes like that, most especially me.)  Come to think of it `$RecursionLimit = 1*^9` is meaningless I believe as that must be greater than the maximum stack depth.  I think a revision to this answer is in order.

Answer (score 14):

If the current position is, say, 2, and the maximum value we allow is, say, 14, we can walk 12 steps with our eyes closed. This attempts to take advantage of that.

`newList` gives the list of new values given the maximum and the starting value.

```
newList = Compile[{{max, _Integer}, {start, _Integer}},
   Module[{aux},
    aux = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, max - start];
    aux[[1]] = start;
    Accumulate[aux]
   ]];
```

Those with v8 or higher can try adding `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` or `CompilationTarget->"C"`

`buildWalkerBag` is the recursive function. It uses bags. It could have been done with linked lists, or sowing and reaping in the end (I tried this at first but it was a little bit slower than the bags)

```
SetAttributes[buildWalkerBag, HoldFirst];

(bwb : buildWalkerBag[bag_, max_])[next_] /; next =!= max := 
  With[{aux = newList[max, next]}, 
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, aux, 1];
      bwb[Last@aux + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]] /; True];

buildWalkerBag[bag_, max_][_] := Internal`StuffBag[bag, max]

walker[max_] := Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity, b = Internal`Bag[]},
      buildWalkerBag[b, max][0];
      Internal`BagPart[b, All]
    ]
```

**USAGE**

`walker[i_Integer?Positive]` where `i` is the maximum position

Comment: Nicely done. +1

Comment: I'm not seeing the need for `/; True` is that left over from something?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it's there to make all that's before `bwb[Last@aux + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]]` a condition, so it returns that last part and is tail recursive

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I usually do this in a different and more explicit way (using `RuleCondition`), but I thought more appropriate to use documented stuff for posts unless there's is a real advantage, right?

Comment: That's a trick worthy of it's own Q/A I think.  It's new to me, unless I'm forgetting, which is at least equally likely.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard come to chat and I'll tell you what I consider the most general version of "the trick"

Comment: @Rojo thanks. How could a time counter be added? So the output would be ${{x1,t1},{x2,t2},...{xn,tn}}$, where time would increase by one unit each step. I can change newList to do that: rand[n_] := Table[{RandomChoice[{-1, 1}], 1}, {n}];newList[max_, start_] := 
  Accumulate@Prepend[rand[max - start - 1], {start, 0}]; but I can't say I understand what's going on in the Bag part. I was able to change Mr. Wizard's code to do this but it was slow so I'm hoping your approach will be faster.

Comment: @BeauGeste you did not mention performance in your question so I did not address it.  How will you be using this function?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard in the end I want to calculate the current so that's why I need to specify some distance and also the time to get there (in the end times between steps will be taken from some distribution also). To get the current to converge, I need to average many runs and this is why I'm looking to speed things up if possible.

Comment: @BeauGeste I see that you Accepted my answer.  Thank you, but I think Rojo's answer is clearly superior if performance is a concern.  I'm still not sure of the details of your problem myself.  For example you say you want *t1, t2, t3* interleaved; cannot this be done with `Riffle` afterward?

Comment: Well, I felt that for the question asked, yours was best as it was concise and simple. Riffle would work if I had a constant time-step but I don't - in fact the time will depend on the hop which can be of varying lengths. Maybe I will post more of the code with more questions for efficiency tips when I get more done on it.

Comment: @BeauGeste I am not sure I understood, but probably it is best to add the times at the end. If they are a function of the step, you can compute the steps with `Differences`, then the times, and then `Riffle`

Answer (score 7):

This is a slight generalization of Mr.Wizard's `NestList` solution. I offer it as an answer because it a bit too long for a comment. The zero step has been eliminated and the test function has been changed to allow non-positive limits.

```
limitedRandomWalk[limit_Integer] :=
   NestWhileList[# + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] &, 0, # != limit &]

SeedRandom[3]

limitedRandomWalk[-10]
```

> {0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, -2, -1, -2, -3, 
>   -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -7, -8, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -6, -5, -6, -5, -6, 
>   -5, -4, -3, -4, -3, -4, -5, -4, -5, -6, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -4, -5, 
>   -6, -7, -8, -9, -10}

```
limitedRandomWalk[10]
```

> {0, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 
>   1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
>   6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 10}

```
 limitedRandomWalk[0]
```

> {0}