# What is the best distribution for my histogram?

Tags: fitting, random, distributions

I defined a security bound for a random walk (cube with 15 length) and I have this code to obtain a sample of the random times at which the random walk crosses the boundary for the first time:

```
w = Do[i = 0; NestWhile[(i++; # + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]) &, {0, 0, 0}, Norm[#] < 15 &];
       Sow[i], {1000}] // Reap
```

(code taken from  [Sample of the random times at which the random walk crosses the boundary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44574/sample-of-the-random-times-at-which-the-random-walk-crosses-the-boundary))

And I constructed a histogram with `w`:

[image: histogram]

And now I want to know the distribution of this data. I thought that it was a gamma because of the histogram, but I ran some tests in Excel and I concluded that it isn't, but I would like to confirm that with *Mathematica*. Is that possible?

And when I do this:

```
\[ScriptCapitalH] = DistributionFitTest[w[[2, 1]], Automatic, "HypothesisTestData"];

\[ScriptCapitalH]["FittedDistribution"]
```

I have for output: `NormalDistribution[233.588, 150.231]`, but `skewness[w] = 1.83` (if it was normally distributed, it should be approximately zero).

Would like some help please :)

Comment: @Szabolcs doesn't this question boil down to "How do I use `DistributionFitTest` to determine whether or not my data fit a gamma distribution?"?  If so, then mma.se may be more appropriate than math.

Comment: @bobthechemist You're right, I was focusing on "And now i want to know the distribution of this data".

Comment: The documentation on this is not at all clear, but I don't think `Automatic` as the second argument does at all what you think.  It *seems* to just assume a normal *dist* and the `Automatic` argument specifies the test type.  (Can anyone cook up an example where `Automatic` returns anything other than `NormalDistribution` ) ?

Comment: Just for clarity, `DistributionFitTest` defaults to a test for normality.  The fitted distribution is NOT the best fitting distribution.  It is the best fitting distribution in the family you are testing. When setting the distribution family to `Automatic` you are using the normal family of distributions.

Comment: thanks for help, didnt find that anywhere @Andy Ross, now i have my answer :)

Comment: The new function `FindDistribution[]` returns a number of useful candidates: `FindDistribution[w[[-1, 1]], 4, All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]`

Comment: Are the estimated parameters for a gamma distribution (or whatever you end up with) going to be used to compare against some other data or simulations from a different set of initial conditions?  If not, why not just use `SmoothHistogram` or `SmoothKernelDistribution`?  (And even if the distribution is approximately a gamma for all practical purposes, with a large enough sample size you'll be guaranteed to reject that distribution with any of the standard tests.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you wanted to automate things you might do something like this:

```
 tests = Sort[(g = 
      DistributionFitTest[
           w, #, {"PValue", "FittedDistribution"}])  & /@  {
               GammaDistribution[a, b, c, d], 
               NormalDistribution[a, b],
               ChiSquareDistribution[a],
               HalfNormalDistribution[a],
               LogNormalDistribution[a, b]}]

 {{0., NormalDistribution[232.755, 156.711]},
 {7.09814*10^-19, ChiSquareDistribution[195.469]}, 
 {1.34007*10^-16, HalfNormalDistribution[0.00446664]}, 
 {0.066279,  GammaDistribution[6.16556, 6.45882, 0.548972, 33.4612]}, 
 {0.0966786, LogNormalDistribution[5.27028, 0.590685]}}

 GraphicsGrid[ 
    Partition[ Show[ {Histogram[w, Automatic, "ProbabilityDensity"],
                      Plot[PDF[#[[2]], x], {x, 0, 1500}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
                 PlotPoints -> 1000 , PlotRange -> {0, 0.008}]}, 
                 PlotRange -> {0, 0.005}, 
                 PlotLabel -> Style[Head[#[[2]]], FontSize -> 10] ] & /@ tests  , 
           3 , 3 , {1, 1} , {}] ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

The mathematica help is very thorough and is very indicative of what you should do next.
By way of the histogram diagram obtained, you can compare your data against the proposed distribution.

```
Show[Histogram[w[[2, 1]], Automatic, "ProbabilityDensity"], 
Plot[PDF[h["FittedDistribution"], x], {x, 0, 1500}, 
PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image: NormalFit]

The reference points you to run the ProbabilityPlot function so you can see how well the curve fits.

```
ProbabilityPlot[w[[2, 1]], h["FittedDistribution"]]
```

[image: ProbabilityPlot]

Not that great.

By further exploring the parametric distributions available in Mathematica, all very well documented in the help , the Gamma distribution looks like a good candidate.

```
dist = GammaDistribution[α, β, γ, μ]
myFit = DistributionFitTest[w[[2, 1]], dist, "HypothesisTestData"]
Show[Histogram[w[[2, 1]], Automatic, "ProbabilityDensity"], 
Plot[PDF[myFit["FittedDistribution"], x], {x, 0, 1500}, 
PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

This looks much more like it.
[image: GammaFit]

```
ProbabilityPlot[w[[2, 1]], myFit["FittedDistribution"]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for help :D not exactly what i wanted but it was really helpfull. I dont understand is why the output for \[ScriptCapitalH]["FittedDistribution"] is not Gammadistribution. And other question when i do KolmogorovSmirnovTest[w[[2, 1]]] mathematica gives me zero, do u have any ideia why this is happening?

Comment: DEar @MarianadaCosta, I'm not privy to how the algorithms have been developed. It might be that Automatic just defaults to the most used distribution, namely, the Normal Distribution. I would recommend that you take a look a look at EDA (exploratory data analysis). A starting point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis