# P-Values are inconsistent when using DistributionFitTest repeatedly

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am attempting to become more familiar with the DistributionFitTest, specifically the distributions it yields and their fittedness.  What I have found is that when I generate random data, fit it, and analyze it, I can repeat the process exactly and get histograms and fits that look very similar, as expected. But, the P-Values from trial to trial (determined by TestDataTable) range from nearly 0 to almost 1.

By running the code shown below multiple times, I produce histograms and PDF's that are quite similar each time, but whose P-Value table varies wildly (eg. Pearson Chi2 has taken on values from 0.04 to 0.96)

```
data=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],10^5];  

fit=DistributionFitTest[data,NormalDistribution[m,s],"HypothesisTestData"];  

fit["TestDataTable",All]  

Show[Histogram[data,30,"PDF"],Plot[PDF[fit["FittedDistribution"],x],{x,-6,6}]]
```

My question is why this would happen?  Based on the histogram/PDF plot, I would expect the P-Values for any given method to be consistently high, or at least *consistent*.

To be clear, I am not interested in why the different methods of computing P-Values differ among one another (eg, why the P-Value found from Cramer-von Mises is different than the Pearson Chi2 P-Value).  Rather, I am curious as to why executing this code a dozen or so times doesn't return similar values for any particular method.  The results from all methods seem to change greatly from trial to trial.

I have perused the Mma documentation of DistributionFitTest and other SE questions concerning this function to no avail. One titled [Inconsistent DistributionFitTest results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44792/inconsistent-distributionfittest-results) informed me of the different behavior DistributionFitTest has when you specify mu and sigma for the Normal Distribution, but the variability of P-Values continues whether or not I specify my mu/sigma when I create and/or fit the data.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is just natural variability in the computed CramerVonMises statistic. `DistributionFitTest` chooses that statistic for your data (as the `"AutomaticTest"` property of the `HypothesisTestData` reveals). Try running this code: `Do[
data=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],10^5];
fit=CramerVonMisesTest[data];
Print@fit
,{10}]` and you'll see similar results.

Comment: @StefanR Thanks for the code, that's a much more compact way of describing the situation.  My question then boils down to how, with 100,000 data points, can the P-Value range from nearly perfect to quite the opposite?  It seems like an awful lot of natural variation.  Or am I misinterpreting how well these fit vis a vie the P-Value?  Better yet, how can I use Mathematica to consistently find a fit for data that matches well.

Comment: Under the null hypothesis the p-value has a uniform distribution on (0,1). So, you would expect 5% of the values to fall at or below 0.05 for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I said in the comments, under the null hypothesis (in this case that the data was drawn from a particular distribution family) the p-value should follow a uniform distribution on (0,1). Let me illustrate with a simple z-test.

```
ztest[data_, mu0_, sigma_] := Block[{z, p, d},
  z = (Mean[data] - mu0)/(sigma/Sqrt[Length[data]]);
  d = NormalDistribution[];
  p = 2*Min[{CDF[d, z], SurvivalFunction[d, z]}];
  {z, p}
  ]
```

We will generate some data that follows a normal distribution with given mean and standard deviation...

```
mu = 2.;
sigma = 3;
rvs = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], {10000, 100}];
```

We can test against a null distribution with the same mean and standard deviation...

```
{z0, p0} = Transpose[ztest[#, mu, sigma] & /@ rvs];
```

And then against an alternative distribution...

```
{z1, p1} = Transpose[ztest[#, mu + .5, sigma] & /@ rvs];
```

Notice that the distribution of the test statistic differs whether the null is true or not.

```
Histogram[{z0, z1}, ChartLegends -> {"Null", "Alt"}]
```

[image]

Under the null, the p-value is uniformly distributed but under the alternative it is skewed towards smaller values.

```
Histogram[{p0, p1}, ChartLegends -> {"Null", "Alt"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is always surprising to undergrad students, and sadly it seems it's often surprising to post-doc researchers.... +1

Comment: @Andy Thank you for your help, your example made it very clear.