# Finding pairs where the intersection of them is empty set from a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, intersection, sets

It would be better to give an example first.
Suppose I have a nested list of the form

```
list = {{ 1,2,3,6}, { 3,6,10,20}, { 4,7,11}, { 10,20}};
```

where each element of `list` is a list of integers from a certain range `(0, max)`.
The `max` number is smaller enough than `Length[list]` and thus I can expect there are many overlaps between elements.

Then I would like to find pairs of position `{x,y}` such that `Intersection[ list[[x]] , list[[y]] ] === {}`. In this example, I should find the pairs `{1,4}` or `{2,3}` but `{1,2}` or `{2,4}` should not be in the result.

Of course, the most naive approach is to make all possible subsets using `Subsets[list,{2}]` then, check every pair. In my case, the length of `list` is around 10^4 so this naive approach does not work in my environment. 
It is guaranteed that the total number of such pairs are much smaller than all possible subsets `n(n-1)/2`. Thus, I have a feeling that there should be a more efficient way to do so but could not find one so far.

Comment: what about {1,3} and {3,4}?  Intersection gives {}

Comment: @Algohi {1,3} and {3,4} should also be included in the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your input specification of integers from 0 through *n* a bit mask should work efficiently:

```
fn[list_] :=
  Pick[
    Subsets[Range @ Length @ list, {2}],
    BitAnd @@@ Subsets[Tr /@ (2^list), {2}],
    0
  ]
```

Test:

```
fn[list]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}
> ```

---

#### Update

I misread your question as indicating that the maximum number is around 10^4, rather than you have 10^4 *lists*.  As you note generating all subsets at once will not work well there.  Instead we will need to operate in blocks<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18203/121)</sup>.

```
fn2[list_, block_: 10000] :=
 With[{
   nums = Tr /@ (2^list),
   n = (# - 1) #/2 & @ Length @ list,
   m = Length @ list
  },
  Join @@
    ParallelTable[
      {i + 1, Min[n, i + block]} /. spec_ :>
        Pick[
          Subsets[Range @ m, {2}, spec],
          BitAnd @@@ Subsets[nums, {2}, spec],
          0
        ],
      {i, 0, n, block}
    ]
 ]
```

The second parameter is the block size, default 10,000.  Test:

```
max = 3000;

big = DeleteDuplicates /@ RandomInteger[max, {10^4, 200}];

fn2[big, 50000] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {17.104978, 77}
> ```

Comment: I really like this as well as the 'separate' function on another recent question,+1 obviously:)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Really cool solution! (+1)!

Comment: @ubpdqn You might find the update of interest.

Comment: @mgamer Thank you.  You also may wish to look at the update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes have added it to my list for contemplation and hopefully use (with attribution of course)